# Get id of div tags using hidden field

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html

I have six div tags in my project and a hidden field. On mouse-over of this each div I want to get the value of div using hidden field. Is there a way out for this?

Below is my code:

```
<div class="item user">

<h2>qhse</h2>   
<div id='qhse' class="qhse" runat="server" > 

</div>

</div>
<div class="item home">
<a href="#" class="icon"> </a>
 <h2>policies</h2>
<div id='hexa' class="hexa" runat="server" > 

</div>
</div>
<div class="item shop">
<a href="#" class="icon"> </a>
<h2>procedures</h2>
<div id='policies' class="policies" runat="server">

</div>
   </div > 
<div class="item camera">
<a href="#" class="icon"></a>
<h2>certificates</h2>
 <div id='certificates' class="certificates" runat="server"  >  


</div>
   </div >
<div class="item fav">
<a href="#" class="icon"></a>
<h2>forms</h2>
<div id='forms' class="forms" runat="server"  >

</div>
   </div >
<div class="item last">
<a href="#" class="icon"></a>
<h2>hexa</h2>
<div id='procedures'  class="procedures" runat="server" >

</div>
   </div >
</div>
```

I wish to get the id of each div in hidden field using javascript.

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {
    $('#nav > div').hover(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.find('div').stop().animate({
             document.getElementById("<%= hdnSelected.ClientID %>").value = "Policies";
        });
```

But doing this method I am getting id of only one div. I need to get id's of all div's.

Thanks

Comment: You need to take a look at JQuery `.each()`

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you.

Comment: Any `selection` or `find()` will return an array of elements, which you can loop through to access individual elements. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: 'I want to get the value of div using hidden field' What is 'the value of the div'? Do you want to set div's id to hidden field value?

Comment: Ya that was a mistake pardon. I want to get id of div's in hidden field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function(){
    var field = $('#<%= hdnSelected.ClientID %>');
    $('#nav').on('mouseover', '.item > div[id]', function() {
       field.val(this.id);
    });
});
```